# Stealing of encryption keys

Tags: private-key

I am new to source code of bitcoin , but so far i have analyzed the source code it seems that encryption keys can be stolen from memory by this technique. This is something hackers often do to steal passwords.

https://www.scribd.com/doc/130070110/Extracting-Encryption-keys-from-RAM

Is there any discussion forum \ talk \ community discussing these issues ?

I have gone through the source code and i don't see any safeguarding controls for prevention of keys as such , like key container etc. Though such attacks are very difficult to do but it is possible.

Comment: Storage of keys seems like off topic here and unrelated to bitcoin. How is this specific to bitcoin?

Comment: bitcoin uses blockchain and blockchain relies completely on digital signatures to define an electronic coin. One of the primary security concerns for digital signatures is the storage of security keys ... if it stolen then ownership of coins can be manipulated ...

Comment: About as on topic as anything remotely related to a computer then by your argument.